# Undefined method "reorder" for #<Array:0xbc38600> using ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have a problem with ActiveAdmin using Ruby ruby 1.9.2p290 and Ruby on Rails 3.2.1.

I used this wiki page to setup the resource for the AdminUsers that works perfectly: [Your First Admin Resource: AdminUser](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/Your-First-Admin-Resource:-AdminUser)

After that I wanted to create the resource for my project model. The migrations for that looks like this:

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :projects do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.boolean :isactive

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class AddSlugToProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :projects, :slug, :string
    add_index :projects, :slug
  end
end
```

My project model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :isactive, :conditions => ["isactive = ?",true]

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :history]

  attr_accessible :name, :description, :isactive

end
```

And that's the project_controller:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    #
    # @projects gets filled in application_controller to be always
    # available for the twitter bootstrap navbar
    # @projects = Project.isactive.find(:all, :order => 'LOWER(name) asc')
    #
  end

  def show
    @project = Project.isactive.find(params[:id])
    if request.path != project_path(@project)
      redirect_to @project, :status => :moved_permanently
    end
  end

end
```

The admin/projects.rb is currently 'empty'

```
ActiveAdmin.register Project do  
end
```

And after all that, everything I get is the following error:

```
Started GET "/admin/projects" for 192.168.0.2 at 2012-02-21 20:58:49 +0100
Processing by Admin::ProjectsController#index as HTML
  Project Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE (isactive = 't') ORDER BY LOWER(name) asc
  AdminUser Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
  Rendered /home/eins11/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.4.1/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb (11.7ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 54ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `reorder' for #<Array:0xa3ecd44>):
    1: render renderer_for(:index)
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/views/pages/index.rb:41:in `items_in_collection?'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/views/pages/index.rb:20:in `main_content'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in build_main_content_wrapper'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/arbre/builder.rb:68:in `block in build_tag'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/arbre/builder.rb:96:in `with_current_dom_context'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/arbre/builder.rb:67:in `build_tag'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/arbre/builder.rb:77:in `insert_tag'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/element.rb:17:in `div'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:115:in `block in build_main_content_wrapper'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/arbre/builder.rb:68:in `block in build_tag'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/arbre/builder.rb:96:in `with_current_dom_context'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/arbre/builder.rb:67:in `build_tag'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/arbre/builder.rb:77:in `insert_tag'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/element.rb:17:in `div'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:114:in `build_main_content_wrapper'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:98:in `block in build_page_content'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/arbre/builder.rb:68:in `block in build_tag'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/arbre/builder.rb:96:in `with_current_dom_context'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/arbre/builder.rb:67:in `build_tag'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/arbre/builder.rb:77:in `insert_tag'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/element.rb:17:in `div'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:97:in `build_page_content'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in build_page'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/arbre/builder.rb:68:in `block in build_tag'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/arbre/builder.rb:96:in `with_current_dom_context'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/arbre/builder.rb:67:in `build_tag'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/arbre/builder.rb:77:in `insert_tag'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/arbre/html/element.rb:17:in `div'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:38:in `block in build_page'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/arbre/builder.rb:96:in `with_current_dom_context'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:37:in `build_page'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:10:in `build'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/arbre/builder.rb:63:in `build_tag'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/arbre/builder.rb:77:in `insert_tag'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/arbre/builder.rb:41:in `method_missing'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/view_helpers/renderer_helper.rb:21:in `render'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb:1:in `__home_eins____rbenv_versions_______p____lib_ruby_gems_______gems_activeadmin_______app_views_active_admin_resource_index_html_arb___523541447_100786690'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:40:in `block in render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:48:in `render_with_layout'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:39:in `render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:12:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:109:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
  /home/eins11/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/resource_controller/actions.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in index'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:229:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:229:in `default_render'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:160:in `to_html'
  responders (0.6.5) lib/responders/flash_responder.rb:93:in `to_html'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:153:in `respond'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:146:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:238:in `respond_with'
  inherited_resources (1.3.0) lib/inherited_resources/actions.rb:7:in `index'
  activeadmin (0.4.1) lib/active_admin/resource_controller/actions.rb:11:in `index'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:469:in `_run__639476650__process_action__1068992826__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:30:in `call'
  journey (1.0.1) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.1) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.1) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:589:in `call'
  sass (3.1.15) lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:54:in `call'
  warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__471556791__call__937320005__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /home/eins11/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
  /home/eins11/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
  /home/eins11/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /home/eins11/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (5.1ms)
  Rendered /home/eins11/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /home/eins11/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (9.8ms)
```

And I have no idea what the problem is...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ah, I've found the solution.
I don't know exactly why the error happened but I had to change my application_controller.

In the application_controller I fetched all projects to @projects:

```
before_filter :getActiveProjects

protected

  def getActiveProjects
    @projects = Project.isactive.find(:all, :order => 'LOWER(name) asc')
  end
```

That was confusing ActiveAdmin. After I changed that to

```
before_filter :getActiveProjects

protected

  def getActiveProjects
    @projects_all = Project.isactive.find(:all, :order => 'LOWER(name) asc')
  end
```

and projects_controller index action to

```
def index
  @projects = @projects_all
end
```

everything worked fine ;)

Comment: How annoying--great find. Worked for me too. I had to restart the Rails server though, for AA to get with the program.

Comment: You can also use `config.skip_before_filter :getActiveProjects` in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb` to avoid loading your projects in ActiveAdmin.

Comment: i believe `:all` causes an array to be returned. However, query like `:order` and `:where` and `:group` only work on instances of  `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

Answer (score 3):

An easier solution is to just skip the filter in the particular active admin controller:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Project do  
    controller do
      skip_before_filter :getActiveProjects
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The active admin make special processing of `@resource` variables. Where `resource` is correponding class name passed to register method. So for code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Project do  
end
```

name of variable is

```
`@project`
```

We must not assign value to variable with such name. Also such varibles may be object of ActiveRecord::Relation class. And how @Oliver write the name like @projects_all is good choice. The using of skip_before_filter is solve the problem too.

One crafty thing need to check. The controller of resource may not have any filters. The controller of resource may not exists at all. What is the filter name to put to skip_before_filter? And where is such filters? The default application controller is used anyway. The filter may be installed at main application controller. The error message of this problem is not informative at all. So need to check application controller for installed filters too.