# undefined method `reorder' for #<Array:0x007fee740c1b78>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I'm using activeadmin and for whatever reason it's not like my Tag model. I don't see anything out of the ordinary about it? google hasnt proved helpful

application_controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :get_tags

  private

  def get_tags
    @tags = Tag.all
  end

end
```

tags_controller

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController

  def search
    @tags = Tag.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @tags.to_json(:only => [:id, :name]) }
    end
  end

  def show
    @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
    @title = @tag.name
  end

end
```

tag model

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.include_root_in_json = false

  has_many :resource_tags
  has_many :resources, :through => :resource_tags

  attr_accessible :name

  validates :name, :presence => true,
                   :length   => { :within => 2..20 },
                   :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

end
```

full trace: http://pastie.org/3641717

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Where in ActiveAdmin are you seeing the error?  Are you hitting this on the index method of the view?  Also, what database are you using?  There are a few "special" issues for some of the less common databases used by rails (SQL Server).

Comment: Everything in admin area works perfect until I hit the tab that says "tags". I'm using sqlite3 in development. The tags also work perfectly on the front-end of the actual site

Comment: stack trace: http://pastie.org/3641717

Comment: related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384346/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that your `Tag` model is conflicting with ActiveAdmins 
`Arbre::HTML::Tag` class. There may be other/better solutions, but one thing that's worked for me in the past is to use the `as:` option in ActiveAdmin.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Tag, as: 'AwesomeTag' do
```

Obviously, the change in copy might be ideal, but it's a good troubleshooting step. Another option is to rename your `Tag` model, or try namespacing it.