# Rails attribute working in console, not in app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I ran a migration on an Image model to add the column Position.

The schema is updated, the column has actually been added to the database, and is accessible through Rails console. I'm even calling an order by clause using that column in ActiveAdmin, and that doesn't grumble .

However when trying to access that attribute in the app, I'm presented with unknown attribute errors.

When trying to display the column in an ActiveAdmin index view, I get:

```
undefined method `position' for #<Image:0x007f8a3429be98>
```

It (position) has been added to attr_accessible too.

I've also run:

```
Image.connection.schema_cache.clear!
Image.reset_column_information
```

and that hasn't helped either.

Rails 3.2.12

Comment: Did you restart the rails server?

Comment: Yep, I've restarted numerous times, cleared cache, nothing...

Comment: Did you run both the console and app in the same environment (dev vs production)?

Comment: What I suggest is checking the data you've set for typos, also what is the output when you run Image from the rails console? did you load the right environment?

Comment: Yep environment was dev both times

Comment: Try to add fake method to Image class: `def position; 0; end` and run it again. If the error appears again - check if the only Image class within the app?

Comment: @dennis output is: `Image(id: integer, title: string, caption: string, image_uid: string, image_name: string, imageable_id: integer, imageable_type: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, position: integer)`

Comment: could you paste some more info of error?? Code where you are using..

Answer (score 0):

After some searching and trying I was able to reproduce the error it was triggered by a before filter.

This post led me to the solution:
[Undefined method "reorder" for #<Array:0xbc38600> using ActiveAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384346/undefined-method-reorder-for-array0xbc38600-usign-activeadmin)

when it helped please upvote the other comment.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow - I don't have any before_filters here. Are you saying I should add one as in the answer in that link?

Comment: The failure should be inside ActiveAdmin as that's the only place it triggers. please check the topic to see if this situation is also found in your application.

Comment: Sorry I can't see how that relates to my situation :S I've just tried on my MBP and it works fine, but not on my Mini that I use for work :( they both have exactly the same setup - same code and database

Comment: Tried on another machine and its working there too - where does that leave me? I've restarted the problem machine, cleared all caches etc :(